# Azure Traffic Manager not balancing traffic between VMs

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-traffic-manager

I have the **following configuration** in Azure:

- 2 xA2 VMs( US-East located), with WAMP installed and Master-Master replication setup for the MySQL DBs.
- 1 Traffic Manager (=TM) to balance traffic between them.
- in Azure portal i have the 'Online' status for both the machines and TM.

I have the **following problem**:

Whatever configuration i choose for the TM (Performance, RR, Failover), i only get entries in the Apache log for only one machine. The only time i get entries for the second machine is only if i have failover and set this machine as the first one in the failover queue.

**Test scenario:**

I am calling a php script with a service from 4 different regions (California, Virginia, Ireland, Japan) to check the traffic distribution, but i never get any logs on the second machine.

Do you have any idea, of what might not function correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Azure Traffic Manager is meant to distribute traffic between different geographic regions (ie. primary site in West US and failover in East US, or performance routing between a West US deployment and North Europe deployment).  If you want to load balance traffic between two VMs in the same datacenter then you should setup a load balanced endpoint - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/08/microsoft-azure-load-balancing-services/.

Comment: thanks @kwill, i guess i rushed a little and configured the TM instead of the LB. Here is also additional info on how to create the LB: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balance-virtual-machines/